# Call a python unittest from another script and export all the error messages

Tags: python, unit-testing

Sorry for the basic question. I have used unittest method to check my models in one script. Now, my question is how do I call this script from another file and save testing results. Below is my code sample:

```
**model_test.py**

import unittest
import model_eq #script has models

class modelOutputTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        #####Pre-defined inputs########
        self.dsed_in=[1,2]

        #####Pre-defined outputs########
        self.msed_out=[6,24]

        #####TestCase run variables########
        self.tot_iter=len(self.a_in)

    def testMsed(self):
        for i in range(self.tot_iter):
            fun = model_eq.msed(self.dsed_in[i],self.a_in[i],self.pb_in[i])
            value = self.msed_out[i]
            testFailureMessage = "Test of function name: %s iteration: %i expected: %i != calculated: %i" % ("msed",i,value,fun)
self.assertEqual(round(fun,3),round(self.msed_out[i],3),testFailureMessage)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The next step I want is to create another script called test_page.py, which runs the unit test script and save results to a variable (I need to post results to a webpage).

```
test_page.py    

from model_test.py import *
a=modelOutputTest.testMsed()
```

However, I got the following errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dropbox\AppPest\rice\Rice_unittest.py", line 16, in &lt;module&gt;
    a= RiceOutputTest.testMsed()
TypeError: unbound method testMsed() must be called with RiceOutputTest instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks!

Thanks for the help from Nix! My next question is: I need to test the function with two given cases in a loop. It is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285010/python-unit-testing-a-loop-function).

Comment: You should split your edit into a new question.

Comment: Why do you have `return a` in your for loop?  You should remove it.

Comment: I moved a the new question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285010/python-unit-testing-a-loop-function

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use a `test runner`

> test runner
>   A test runner is a component which orchestrates the execution of tests and provides the outcome to the user. The runner may use a graphical interface, a textual interface, or return a special value to indicate the results of executing the tests.

```
from unittest.case import TestCase
import unittest
from StringIO import StringIO
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def testTrue(self):
        '''
        Always true
        '''
        assert True

    def testFail(self):
        '''
        Always fails
        '''
        assert False

from pprint import pprint
stream = StringIO()
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(stream=stream)
result = runner.run(unittest.makeSuite(MyTestCase))
print 'Tests run ', result.testsRun
print 'Errors ', result.errors
pprint(result.failures)
stream.seek(0)
print 'Test output\n', stream.read()
```

---

```
>>> Output:  
>>> Tests run  2
>>> Errors  []
>>> [(<__main__.MyTestCase testMethod=testFail>,
>>> 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "leanwx/test.py", line 15, in testFail\n                assert False\nAssertionError\n')]
>>> Test output
>>> F.
>>> ======================================================================
>>> FAIL: testFail (__main__.MyTestCase)
>>> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
>>>   File "leanwx/test.py", line 15, in testFail
>>>     assert False
>>> AssertionError
>>>
>>>----------------------------------------------------------------------
>>>Ran 2 tests in 0.001s
>>>
>>>FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping with this issue!!! I have been learning your examples. One question, is there any documents I can find all the available methods for unittest.TextTestRunner (like result.testsRun, result.errors)? Also for stream.read()?

Comment: This might be of help:  http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult  it shows most of the things you can access in test runner.  As for stream its a stringio which is a "file like" string.  It should not be used if you are going to have a lot of output.  You should write the output to a file instead, and then read from it.

Comment: Last question... Should I include 'assertNotEqual' if I want to print some messages about a function is successfully tested?

Comment: I dont follow that question.

Comment: Sorry. Currently, if assertEqual fails, I will get an error message. I am wondering if I can generate a successful message once assertEqual is passed.

Comment: Not sure why you want to do that, you can pass `unittest.TextTestRunner(stream=stream, verbosity=2)` and it will result in something like: `testTrue (__main__.MyTestCase) ... ok`

Comment: Is it true that only the first iteration of the loop has been tested? Please check the updated post.

Comment: In python3, this works for me with no stream argument: `runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(); result = runner.run(unittest.makeSuite(MyTestCase)); print(result)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your unit tests located in the "test" directory:

```
# Tested in Python 3.8
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#module-unittest
from unittest import TestLoader, TestResult
from pathlib import Path


def run_tests():
    test_loader = TestLoader()
    test_result = TestResult()

    # Use resolve() to get an absolute path
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve
    test_directory = str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / 'test')

    test_suite = test_loader.discover(test_directory, pattern='test_*.py')
    test_suite.run(result=test_result)

    # See the docs for details on the TestResult object
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult

    if test_result.wasSuccessful():
        exit(0)
    else:
        # Here you can either print or log your test errors and failures
        # test_result.errors or test_result.failures
        exit(-1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_tests()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.py` from header `from model_test.py import *`